# Graph API to share on Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flutter

I'm working on flutter app. I have been searching from last 4 hours but didn't find. Is there any way to share **IMAGE+CONTENT+URL** on Facebook.

> ~ Facebook integration is done by me I have got token, facebookID

Comment: What is the question? What had you tried so far? Where did you failed?

Comment: @Selvin Yes I have tried and fail to find graph-url

Comment: Use the share dialog and share a URL that contains og:image and og:description

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the graph API says they have deprecated the ability to post to the users feed from the graph API.

[image]

The graph-api documentation links to a new section called "sharing products" There are separate sections for iOS, Android and Web. I don't use flutter, so I don't have any info on how to integrate these into your app. You'll have to read the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing